# searching against arraylist from user input

Tags: java

I have done this but for loop isn"t working
would someone correct this ??

```
package bankapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BankApp {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Accounts> accounts = new ArrayList<Accounts>();
      Accounts acct = new Accounts();

      acct.setFname("Arsh");
      acct.setLname("Singh");
      acct.setId(1001);
      acct.setBalance(1232.09);
      accounts.add(acct);

      acct.setFname("Gagan");
      acct.setLname("Deep");
      acct.setId(1002);
      acct.setBalance(3500.3);
      accounts.add(acct);


      acct.setFname("love");
      acct.setLname("Deep");
      acct.setId(1003);
      acct.setBalance(3535.5);
      accounts.add(acct);

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter User Id");
           int id = input.nextInt();

       class SearchUser { 
          public int SearchId(int id ){

              for (Accounts account : accounts) {
                  if (account.getId() == id) {
                System.out.println("which account do you want to Access ?(S for Savings and C for checkings)");
                  }
              }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Please be more specific. "It's not working" is not a question.

Comment: What is the error are you getting? What's your expected output?

Comment: Also, you're not showing the `Accounts` class.

Comment: As you are using the same `Accounts` object, all objects in the List will have the same values.

Comment: Please add breakpoints to your code and try to debug line by line. then you will understand what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Although your post is vague, I can already tell you your problem is this part of your code :

```
  Accounts acct = new Accounts();

  acct.setFname("Arsh");
  acct.setLname("Singh");
  acct.setId(1001);
  acct.setBalance(1232.09);
  accounts.add(acct);

  acct.setFname("Gagan");
  acct.setLname("Deep");
  acct.setId(1002);
  acct.setBalance(3500.3);
  accounts.add(acct);


  acct.setFname("love");
  acct.setLname("Deep");
  acct.setId(1003);
  acct.setBalance(3535.5);
  accounts.add(acct);
```

You only have one account object and you are adding the same object multiple times to the array. If you try to print the array you will get 3 "love Deep", because all the previous data is being overwritten.

Declare multiple new accounts like this :

```
  Accounts acct = new Accounts();
  Accounts acct1 = new Accounts();
  Accounts acct2 = new Accounts();

  acct.setFname("Arsh");
  acct.setLname("Singh");
  acct.setId(1001);
  acct.setBalance(1232.09);
  accounts.add(acct);

  acct1.setFname("Gagan");
  acct1.setLname("Deep");
  acct1.setId(1002);
  acct1.setBalance(3500.3);
  accounts.add(acct1);


  acct2.setFname("love");
  acct2.setLname("Deep");
  acct2.setId(1003);
  acct2.setBalance(3535.5);
  accounts.add(acct2);
```